# Form validation with Form component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I am unsure on how to do form validation with the antd `<Form/>` component found [here](https://ant.design/components/form/). The documentation specifies an `onSubmit` prop on the `<Form/>` component, which is passed an event. It then seems to trigger a function inside `this.props.form`. I am currently using the following code:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

  console.log('before' + e.target.value)

  this.props.validateFields((err, values) => {
  console.log('errors: ' + err)
  console.log(values)
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    }
  });
}

<Form inline onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
    ....
</Form>
```

1. I am unable to retrieve values from the event passed into the submit callback, as `e.target.value` returns undefined.

   2. In the call to `this.props.validateFields()`, as shown in the documentation, where are these values coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole form data is managed by antd Form component, So you don't need to get then by `e.target.value`, what you need is to call

```
this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
```

When ever you want to do the validation. this callback provides you if there is an error or the full set of form data.

`values` comes from the form props which is injected by `Form.create();`

`this.props.form` is also injected by `Form.create()`, otherwise you will get undefined, eg:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
}

export default Form.create()(MyComponent);
```

You can also use `validateFieldsAndScroll` instead of `validateFields`  which will automatically scroll to the field where an error is ocurred.

Comment: This is what I originally tried, but `form` was consistently undefined. As it is a prop I assume it needs to be passed in by the parent component. How do you pass in a prop in a nested field such as `this.props.form.validateFields`, and what would the signature of that function look like in the parent?

Comment: the `this.props.form` is injected by a higher order function from `Form.create`, let me update the answer

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up with. The errors were being caused by missing a `.bind(this)` on several of the handlers, causing issues with the props. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late also not sure you had the same issue. but recently I had the issue like form values are not getting for me. So I have used below code and its working fine for me. May it will help someone else.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }

        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
    });
}
```

and in the form

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```